# How to deploy multiple Next.js projects in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, next.js, microservices, amazon-eks

I have deployed a Kubernetes cluster in AWS EKS. Everything works perfectly as expected.
Previously I had one single services named `client` and my `ingress-service.yaml` file was look like this one:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-service
  labels: 
    app: my-service
  annotations:
  # ...... removed to focus on the spec part
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

So, I can access my next.js homepage perfectly without any issues.

Now, I have another project `admin`, which is configured to run on a different port `3001`.

My updated `ingress-service.yaml` file:

```
# ...... removed to focus on the spec part
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /admin/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
               service:
                 name: admin-srv
                 port:
                   number: 3001
```

Admin page loads but without any CSS or JS files and I see that errors in web browser's `console` that all files under `/_next/ are forbidden.

So I modified my `ingress-service.yaml`, add a path `/_next/` for the Admin under `admin-srv` something like the following:

```
    ...... removed to focus on the spec part
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /admin/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
               service:
                 name: admin-srv
                 port:
                   number: 3001
          - path: /_next/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
               service:
                 name: admin-srv
                 port:
                   number: 3001
```

What happens now is my admin page `http://some-service-rule.xxxx/admin/login` loads perfectly but client `http://some-service-rule.xxxx` messed up missing all CSS and JS files.

I can understand that all requests for the client `/_next/` is now going to the `admin-srv` and the requested files for the client is forbidden.

So, how can I add multiple `/_next/` paths for multiple projects in a same Kubernetes cluster?

Any help is much appreciate.

Comment: If you're ok with having subdomain, putting `/admin` to a subdomain like admin.foo.com, can fix your ingress. You can use `host:` https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/main/content/en/examples/service/networking/ingress-wildcard-host.yaml like this.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a domain yet.